# Populate a custom list view with two textviews and a checkbox

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have created the `main.xml` and the `list.xml`
my java class extends `menuActivity`
I have 2 vectors--

```
 Vector<String> name=new Vector<String>();
   Vector<String> nickname=new Vector<String>();
```

i have created my `custom holder class` too.
my question is how do i pass this two list into my adapter class.
which adapter should i use?

i tried putting this two vectors inside another list and sending that list to my custom adpater class.But it didnt work out.
I am stuck here.
What is the difference between baseadpater and an array adapter?

Comment: take a look into examples api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All BaseAdpater does is solidify the callbacks necessary for a for an AbsListView. An ArrayAdater is a more comprehensive adapter that auto-inflates a list of items into a TextViews.

For your situation, I recommend extending BaseAdapter:

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Vector<String> names;
    Vector<String> nicks;

    public MyAdapter(Vector<String> nms, Vector<String> nks) {
        if (nms.size() != nks.size())
            throw new RuntimeException("oops! Wrong sizes for vectors");
        name = nms;
        nicks = nks;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return names.getSize() &&  nicks.getSize();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem() {
        // Can't really implement with two vectors.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public getView(int pos, View convert, ViewGroup mommy) {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)convert;

        if (ll == null)
            // Inflate the linear layout - preferrably from resources

        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder)ll.getTag();

        if (vh == null)
            // Inflate ViewHolder

        vh.tvname.setText(names.get(pos));
        vh.tvnick.setText(nicks.get(pos));
        return ll;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvname, tvnick;
    }
}
```